# How can I set some clear and informative value for SUITES?

Tags: python, pytest, allure, automation-testing

I use pytest and allure, and I want to put into SUITES something more informative instead of tests.incident.addd_incident. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this Github issue](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-pytest/issues/141), all you need to do is decorate your test function with `@allure.title`:

```
@allure.title("Descriptive title for test")
def test_add_incident(self):
    ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me for some reason.
    @allure.title("API01_add_incident")
    def test_add_incident_status_code_200(data_for_status_code_test, add_incident):
        role = add_incident.role
        expected_code, real_code = data_for_status_code_test
        assert expected_code == real_code